# gradlew commands showing no result

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I am trying to run following commands on Terminal window of Android Studio, but nothing is coming in result:

```
ms-macbook-3868:ProjectName my_name$ ./gradlew install
ms-macbook-3868:ProjectName my_name$ ./gradlew bintrayUpload
ms-macbook-3868:ProjectName my_name$
```

Is this issue with Android Studio?
Please help.

Comment: Do you have gradlew files?

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException Can you please tell how can I check that? I think `gradlew` is installed that's why it is not showing `command not found`

Comment: In your project files I mean

Comment: I have `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat` and  `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: `$ gradle` commands running ok? Can you use `./gradlew` through Terminal (cmd on windows?)

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException Yes.